# Is it possible to use InheritedWidget as a mixin?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to see if I can add some generic navigation behavior passed around my app, and I see that `InheritedWidget` is a great candidate to avoid passing a specific callback around the widget tree, however I'm noticing more and more that I can only have `InheritedWidget` of specific class type in order to make the InheritedWidget pattern work, and I was wondering if there's a way to use `InheritedWidget` as a mixin or if there's a better alternative.

My app looks like this, it passes a callback down the tree

[image]

I have 3 navigators right now that I need to present the same method but to act on it themselves right now I need to create 3 InheritedWidget navigators, but the problem is that any widget under the tree would either have to do

`NavigatorA.of(context).pushWidget()`

But I'd much rather prefer if it was a generic `GenericNavigator.of(context).pushWidget()` so that I the leaf widgets don't even need to know the right value of the navigator object, I'm afraid to achieve this I'd need to be able to use InheritedWidget as a mixin

This is the desired flow, no callbacks passed

[image]

Is this the correct strategy or is there a better way? 
How can I use InheritedWidget as a mixin?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot make `InheritedWidget` as a mixin.

However, you can make a generic `InheritedWidget`:

```
class Provider<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  Provider({Key key, this.value, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static T of<T>(BuildContext context) {
    Provider<T> provider = context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<T>();
    return provider?.value;
  }

  final T value;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(Provider<T> oldWidget) {
    return value != oldWidget.value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I my case I need `NavigatorA`,`NavigatorB` and `NavigatorC` to intercept the calls and present on their own local navigators the new widget, however they are Stateful widgets, so it's impossible to extend StatefulWidget and InheritedWidget at the same time

Comment: Use two different widgets. One that is a statefulWidget and another that is an InheritedWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @RémiRousselet's answer

Working with flutter 1.19+, where some `inheritedWidget` APIs are deprecated,  the `of` should look like this now:

```dart
    static T of<T>(BuildContext context) {
      return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<Provider<T>>().value;
    }
```

Since the api is based on generics, you no longer need the `_typeof` tricks.